# Custom Format for LOT Number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to have a custom format for a production LOT number. This is a running number for each year. E.g. production lot **17 235554** means: it is the 235554th production LOT for 2017.

How to set the code or the separator in the custom format cell? I would like to type **17235554** in the cell and get a result of **17 235554**.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the cell, format and use custom and create your own.

Answer (score 0):

Two assumptions before we format the data,

1) Your LOT number is always 6 digits and year is 2 digits totaling 8 digits:

- Select the column you want to format and press `CTRL` + `1`.
- In number tab, in custom category, type the custom format as `00 000000`

2) The length of your LOT number might vary. The year is always 2 digits but the LOT number can be 4, 5, 6 or 7 digits. In that case apply conditional formatting for each of the case.

- Select the columns you want to format
- In home tab, click conditional formatting --> new rule
- Select "Use formula to determine which cells to format"
- In the formula box enter the formula `=A1/1000000>=17` (The 17 is for the year)
- Click format and do the same as in case 1 and click ok
- If you want to do this for a 5 digit LOT, your formula should be `=A1/100000>=17`

Hops this helps. Let me know in case of any clarification

Comment: I have the version 1. However, If I appy your advice this is the result: 17 123 456. It seems there is a thousend separator there. Thank you.

Comment: @JozsefGarab You have to remove the thousand seperator